# Zend 2 REST Client Post Method sending header parameters also

Tags: php, web-services, rest, zend-framework2, client

In the Zend Framework 2, using REST Client using the POST method, the post `URL` has the query string,

As normal in postman when the request is post, the post content i have set
`{"authToken":"11111111111111"}` and post, status success.

when i get this value using GET method i have get the response, `{"authToken":"11111111111111"}`

which is correct.

when i run this through, php zend 2 using below method,

```
protected function genericSendRequest($url, $rawJsonData = NULL, $param = array()){
    $response = '';
    if(!empty($param)) {
      $url .= '?' . http_build_query($param);
    }
    $client = $this->getHttpClient();
    $client->setUri($url);
    $client->setMethod('POST');
    if($rawJsonData != null) {
      $client->setRawBody(json_encode($rawJsonData));
    }

    $response = $client->send();
    if ($response->isSuccess()) {
        return $response->getContent();
    }
    return NULL; 
}
```

Request Input,

`$rawJsonData = array("authToken"=>"11111111111111");
 $param = array("id"=>"9e770c9f71b4ef1b4ae85c58b0be4280253f9a2e");`

Response i got,

`id=9e770c9f71b4ef1b4ae85c58b0be4280253f9a2e&%7B%22authToken%22%3A%2211111111111111%22%7D=`

This look like a URL query string,

i need the the response `{"authToken":"11111111111111"}`

ie. I need to get what i have post but i am getting post + query string,

query string is additionally posting to the request, that so its getting in the response,

how should avoid posting this querying string.

what the change needed in my code.?

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You question isn't very clear, but assuming you want to POST JSON data rather than form encoded data, you want:

```
if ($rawJsonData != null) {
    $client->setRawBody(json_encode($rawJsonData));
}
```

Also, you could rewrite the query string part of your function to just:

```
if (!empty($param)) {
    $uri .= '?' . http_build_query($param);
}
```

Comment: i have used this `$client->setRawBody(json_encode($rawJsonData));` but getting the same response

Comment: The response is down to whatever API you are POSTing to - what makes you think that this isn't the correct response?

Comment: I need the `posting values` as response, i am getting the `posted values + query string` as response

Comment: Like I said, the *response* is not something you have any control over. That's completely down to the API you're posting to.

Comment: The query string is *not* being added to the POST data (at least not in the code you posted). It's much more likely that the API you're POSTing to, when responding with the request parameters, includes parameters from both the query string and POST data. But a) if so, this isn't something you have control over; and b) it's impossible to know this for sure without knowing what API you're trying to use.

Comment: This API, just store the POST data, and can retrieve that data by using GET method